# Adding values from text file to 2D Array c#

Tags: c#, arrays, parsing, unity-game-engine, 2d

EDITED---
I was having trouble adding values to a 2D Array in my foreach loop. Hari pointed out that I needed to declare i = 0 and my array before the loop and that I had the assignments of the value backwards. (Thank you).
However, I have tried to add a final intensity array and Debug.Log the values for i and the console reads "System.Single[]" instead of the value of the single. Any idea why this is?
 Thank you!!

Here is my code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

//[Serializable]
public class MultiArrayList2 : MonoBehaviour {

public TextAsset datafile;
private int i;
private float[,] coordinates;
private float[] intensity;

// Use this for initialization
void Start() {

    string[] dataLines = datafile.text.Split ('\n');
    string[] lineValues;
    //print (dataLines.Length);
    i=0;

    float[,] coordinates = new float[6853, 3];  
    float[] intensity = new float[6853];
    foreach (string line in dataLines) {

        lineValues = line.Split (' ');
        float coordinateX = float.Parse (lineValues [0]);
        float coordinateY = float.Parse (lineValues [1]);
        float coordinateZ = float.Parse (lineValues [2]);
        float intens = float.Parse (lineValues [3]);

        coordinates [i, 0] = coordinateX;
        coordinates [i, 1] = coordinateY;
        coordinates [i, 2] = coordinateZ;

        intensity [i] = intens;

        Debug.Log (intensity);

        i++;        

    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few points.

1. You have not initilaized `i`, initialze this variable before loop (`foreach`)
2. Move your `coordinates`  initialization to next line.
3. You have to uncomment commented lines (That is what you need).
4. `Debug.Log` always looks for 1st coordinate, I beleive you want to for each coordinate, change it to `i`.

Try this.

```
i=0;
int[,] coordinates = new int[6853, 3];  

foreach (string line in dataLines) {

    lineValues = line.Split (' ');
    int coordinateX = int.Parse (lineValues [0]);
    int coordinateY = int.Parse (lineValues [1]);
    int coordinateZ = int.Parse (lineValues [2]);
    float intensity = float.Parse (lineValues [3]);

    coordinates [i, 0] = coordinateX;
    coordinates [i, 1] = coordinateY;
    coordinates [i, 2] = coordinateZ;

    Debug.Log(coordinates [i, 0]);
    i++;        
}
```

Comment: Glad to help you, mark it as an answer if this helped you and it is the solution to the question.

Answer (score 0):

you are not assigning anything to the array elements , when first you make your array its elements contains no value then you are assigning them to `coordinateX`    it should be the other way around ,

```
 coordinates [i, 0] = coordinateX;
```